# Html.Partial concatenate string to form full path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to concatenate the full path of a partial view to render the required view. My attempt below is not working, any ideas why?

```
<li>@Html.Partial("~/Views/Widget/" + @widget.WidgetID.ToString() + ".cshtml", null)</li>
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 closing )?

Comment: Typo, see the edited, latest version above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the .cshtml.

This works:

```
@{string bla = "pick";}
@Html.Partial("_Date" + bla + "er")
```

If I add .chtml after "er" it doesn't work.